# How to adding detail to low poly style model for game engine

Tags: workflow

Want to add some detail to a low poly style castle Wall model, make the bricks some variation, move in and out and cut some corner, build a scene in unity and found that with a direaction light, lowpoly with flat color could nearly lose all detail and become flat in shadow side. How to perserve at least some detail at shadow side?

Comment: Use diffuse map and bump map, or a normal map perhaps?

Comment: want to generate a cavity map and mix with diffuse map, is there a quick way not use high poly to bake?

Comment: You can bake a cavity diffuse map from something and overlay that map on your object diffuse map by *darken* or *enlighten* using GIMP or similar image processing tools. **Substance Painter** will be a better chose if you want more control and detail on your low poly mesh from scratch.